# Xpath working in firepath but not in scrapy

Tags: xpath, scrapy

In [google finance](https://www.google.com/finance?q=%27&restype=company&noIL=1&num=10&ei=VPBjWJHKK9S7U6_dmvgM&start=0) I want to save the rows of the table containing the companies info but the xpath that works with firepath ie `.//*[@id='gf-viewc']/div/div[2]/form/table/tbody/child::*` yield and empty list in scrapy using the command `response.xpath('.//*[@id='gf-viewc']/div/div[2]/form/table/tbody/child::*').extract()`.

Any idea why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tbody` is something you should exclude from the expression - it is *generated by a browser* to "support the table structure":

```
response.xpath(".//*[@id='gf-viewc']/div/div[2]/form/table/child::*").extract()
```

While this works, I'd improve on locating the table and it's rows:

```
response.css("table.company_results tr")
```

Comment: how do I get rid of thead ? I want to select children of tbody only basically

Comment: @ChiseledAbs would this work for you `response.css("table.company_results tr")[1:]`?

Comment: @ChiseledAbs yup, if you want to extract it, you can call `.extract()`.

Comment: ye realized that and deleteted my comment. In fact it's a good thing it even removes the last row where you select the pages. Any idea why ?